# How can I hide my custom html5 video controls when the user is inactive?

Tags: javascript, html

I have some custom html5 video controls and I'd like to hide them when a user is watching the video. I'll wait two seconds and if they're not moving their mouse, I'll hide the controls, then when they move the mouse again I'll show the controls.

What's a practical, performing way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Use `mousemove` event with `setTimeout`

Clear the `setTimeout` if `mouse` is moving

```js
var elem = document.getElementById('controls');
var timeout;
var duration = 3000;
document.addEventListener('mousemove', function() {
  elem.textContent = 'Mouse is moving!'
  clearTimeout(timeout);
  timeout = setTimeout(function() {
    elem.textContent = 'Mouse Has stopped!'
  }, duration)
});
```

```html
<div id="controls">Mouse Has stopped!</div>
```

### [Fiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/rayon_1990/57q0qvjn/1/)

---

**Implementation using `controls` attribute**

```js
var video = document.getElementById('videoElem');
var timeout;
var duration = 500;
document.addEventListener('mousemove', function() {
  video.setAttribute("controls", "controls");
  clearTimeout(timeout);
  timeout = setTimeout(function() {
    video.removeAttribute("controls");
  }, duration)
});
```

```css
html {
  padding: 20px 0;
  background-color: #efefef;
}
body {
  width: 400px;
  padding: 40px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: #fff;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
video {
  width: 400px;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<video preload controls id="videoElem">
  <source id="mp4" src="http://grochtdreis.de/fuer-jsfiddle/video/sintel_trailer-480.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

### [Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rayon_1990/NpgD5/1058/)

Comment: The example is incredibly jittery. As soon as you do it for about a minute, it starts to flicker.

Comment: @Costa, Missed the `key` in code.. __`clearTimeout`__

Comment: I'm using the timeupdate event and that's working nicely. I don't think timeouts are the way to go here.

Comment: @Costa, Any reason of not using `timeout` ?

Comment: I ended up using this to create a 'scrubbing' feature. So that when you click and drag the 'thumb' on the video seekbar, it will update the video, but not constantly on mousemove, that's nuts, it'll do so only after 100 milliseconds or so of keeping the mouse still. Any chance a requestionAnimationFrame version of your example could would be better? I ask mostly from a learning standpoint.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using the timeupdate event:

```
var counts = 0
function hideOnIdle (video) {
  if (video.paused === true) return controls.classList.remove('hidden')
  if (counts > 7) {
    controls.classList.add('hidden')
    counts = 0
  }
  counts += 1
}

document.addEventListener('mousemove', function (event) {
  controls.classList.remove('hidden')
  counts = 0
}, false)
```

Comment: Under the context of `video`, this will go nicely.. My solution is more of a generalized one ;)